# Draw Meshlines for specific z-coordinate and where x==y

Tags: plotting, mesh

I want to draw a Meshline where `x==y` and where `z==4`. The following code does neither. (The x==y line is horribly jagged and the red line does not show up at all)

```
exampleList = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x + y^2}, {x, 1, 2, 0.1}, {y, 1, 2, 0.1}], {1, 2}]
ListPlot3D[exampleList, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, If[#1 == #2, #3] &}]
ListPlot3D[exampleList, Mesh -> {{1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}, {1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}, {{4, Red}}}]
```

My Mathematica version is `13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using ``ListPlot3D`` and not ``Plot3D[x + y^2, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}]``?

Comment: @Domen yes, I generate external data which are plotted with ListPlot3D. This is just some dummy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[ListPlot3D[exampleList, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}], 
 ListPlot3D[exampleList, MeshFunctions -> {#2 - #1 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, Red}}}]]
ListPlot3D[exampleList, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}, {1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}, {{4, Red}}}]
```

[image]
[image]